# How to properly use async await

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I tried out a few things with async/await but I dont't realy get it. All I want to achive for the beginning is to concurrently write to the Console from two different Threads. Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomethingAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Console.Write(".");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingAsync enter");

    //This does not seem good
    await Task.Delay(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Console.Write("X");

    Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingAsync exit");
}
```

With Threads that was easy but with async/await I only get it done when I put in this strange

```
await Task.Delay(1);
```

Most basic examples I saw used this. But what to do, when you want to do something timetaking that is not async? You cant await anything and so all code runs on the main Thread.
How can I achive the same behavior as with this code but without using Task.Delay()?

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: Have a look at my [async-await curation](https://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parallel and concurrent are not the same thing. If you want your `for` loop to be executed in parallel use `Task.Run` to offload that work to a different `ThreadPool` thread:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Console.Write(".");

    task.Wait() 
}

static void DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Console.Write("X");
}
```

`async-await` is used for asynchronous operations, which *may* run concurrently but not **necessarily**.

Comment: To elaborate on the async/await question: it's important to understand what these keywords do and what they don't do. In particular, they do _not_ actually cause anything to run asynchronously. What they _do_ do is tell the compiler that the async method is expected to invoke some kind of operation that will complete asynchronously, where the method wants to wait for the completion of that operation and then continue with something else. Without something to "await" in the async method, it just completes straight through like a normal method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `async Task` method and call `Wait` on the resulting task. This will work. It will, however, introduce concurrency because timer ticks are served on the thread pool. I'm not sure what thread-safety guarantees the console makes.

[Consider setting up a single threaded synchronization context.](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) Such a thing behaves very much like a UI thread. All your code runs single threaded, yet you can have multiple async methods executing.